# Regarding differentiating html tag from xml tag in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a validation to allow if it is xml tag and stop if it is html tag. Searched through the internet , couldn't find the answer . So i am posting this question. The validation can be done using javascript or jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example? What did you try?

Comment: have a reg ex to find all the tags but i dont know how to differentiate htm land xml tags.

Comment: What would constitute a valid tag? Do you mean to say that `<body>` would be invalid but `<cocacola>` would be valid, as it is not a standard HTML tag? Also, what is "it" in your first sentence? An input string that contains a single tag?

Comment: i am having a text box which should accept xml tag and not html tag.

Comment: What do you consider an "xml tag"? XML elements can have any name. `<body>` is just a valid in XML as in HTML.

Comment: @RoToRa Thats the issue , i need to differentiate html from xml .

Comment: @RoToRa XML tag can be any word with <xml>.

Comment: **YOU** have to know what **YOU** consider "XML" first. It doesn't seem that you actually know what XML is.

Comment: No, XML is not "any word with <xml>". What do you mean mean with "word"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64935/discussion-between-elayaraja-and-rotora).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can differentiate a xml tag from a html tag just using a regular expression or something like that.

Both, xml and html are subsets of sgml, and although they have been designed with different purposes they are too related from a syntax point of view to allow you to differentiate two tags just by it's syntax.

Things became even more complicated if we add different versions of the languages or add xhtml to the mix.

The fact is, from a strict point of view, you could get a collection of all html specification tags and compare your current tag against it, however if it matches you won't be able to assure that it isn't a xml tag.

I think that you're trying to approach syntactically a semantic problem.